# Add Term Frequencies From Multiple Documents (Solr)

Tags: solr, lucene

How can you use Solr math operations or function queries to add the term frequency (tf) values for each word for all documents returned by a query?

I know that there are ways to iteratively add term vectors using java, but that can take a long time if the index is large or memory is limited. Solr has the primitive term frequency values and the ability to add normal field values, so I think it should be able to add term frequencies, I just don't know how.

Also, I do not know what the words are ahead of time, each document can have any combination of words.

For this doc result:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "content": [
      "FOO FOO BAR"
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "content": [
      "FOO BAR"
    ],
  },
]},"termVectors": [
"uniqueKeyFieldName",
[
  "0",
  [
    "FOO",
    [
      "tf",
      2
    ],
    "BAR",
    [
      "tf",
      1
    ],
],"1",
  [
    "FOO",
    [
      "tf",
      1
    ],
    "BAR",
    [
      "tf",
      1]]}
```

I would like something like this instead:

```
{"frequencies":{
"FOO" : 3
"BAR" : 2
}
```

UPDATE:
I am now OK with a programmatic approach using Java because I do not think SOLR supports an operation like this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

[`totaltermfreq` or `ttf`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#totaltermfreq) provides the total number of times the terms occurs in the index.

Comment: Yes I found those and they are helpful but not what I am looking for. I am looking for the sum of the term frequencies for only the documents returned by the query, not the entire index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered "[facet](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview)" feature?

Comment: I do not believe facets are what I am looking for because I cannot afford to create additional faceted fields for my main content (the content I was the frequencies for). That would effectively double the size of my index and that is too much disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Stats Component? It's possible to define dynamic fields as `stats.field`. See `stats.field={!func}termfreq('text','memory')` in the [Solr Stats Component example](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/the-stats-component.html#stats-component-example):

`http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&stats=true&stats.field={!func}termfreq('text','memory')&stats.field=price&stats.field=popularity&rows=0&indent=true`